# Алгоритм для игры крестики-нолики

Tags: алгоритм

Можете подсказать есть ли какой алгоритм, который можно было бы использовать в качестве инициатора действий со стороны ИИ для игры против людей средней сложности в крестики-нолики?
Я планировал 3 уровня сложности: лёгкий, средний, тяжёлый. Так вот для тяжелого у меня написан minimax, для легкого буду пихать просто в свободные ячейки, а вот для среднего не знаю что выбрать.

Comment: *Какие* крестики-нолики? 3х3? :)

Comment: @Harry конечно)

Comment: Тогда даже не представляю, как вы найдете целых три уровня в эту игру (каковая отлично программировалась даже не калькуляторе типа Б3-34)... Без всякого минимакса :)

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно какой может быть ИИ в крестиках-ноликах, учитывая довольно скудное количество комбинаций.

Например, тот кто ходит первым, не может проиграть при оптимальной игре, однако есть ходы, которые "возможно" неочевидны(опять вспомним про скудное количество вариантов), в таком случае можно рандомить между точно хорошей и потенциально хорошей ячейкой.